# How can i have numbers from 2 columns match and return a third result?

Tags: ms-office

I would greatly appreciate some help with this task. Is there any formula could I use in Excel to have cells in 2 columns find a match and produce a third result? The table below is the example:

The 1st column is random numbers. The second column contains the same numbers but is ordered. the 3rd row has numbers that correspond to the ordered number row. I'm trying to figure out how you can have the random number row find its match in the ordered row and return the value of the third row.

Here is what I need to happen...

Cell A1 is 1030303, the matching number is in cell C10. I need the formula to have A1 return the value of E10 and for all the other numbers to do the same according to their match

[image]

Comment: I expect you can do what you describe above using a formula combining the `match()` and `index()` functions in Excel. You may also get all of what you need solely from the `rank()` function if what you need actually is simply the ranks of items in column A.

Comment: Nothing to do with Apple. Doesn’t belong here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in [help].  [su] might be a better fit?

Comment: This would need an edit to explain what version of excel and how it’s running on Apple gear to be on topic. See the [tour] for the short version of what’s on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is how you can use index() with match() in column B to get the result from column E, it won't replace the contents of column A unless you do something with vba.
[image]